# How to bind extracted parameters in WebTest VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, webtest

I am using VS2010 WebTest to inovoke a list of WCF operations in sequence.

First call is to obtain a session token from the server. This token has to be passed as request element to all subsequent calls. I have extracted this `token` and stored this into `Context` as `MyToken`.

[image]

I need your help to find out how to bind `MyToken` into subsequent `xml requests`.

Is there any directive like `<%# %>` for this purpose.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of more search, I have found out that we can use double curly braces to bind `Context Parameters` in string body of the request Xmls. As below -

```
{{MyToken}}
```

Visual Studio replaces these token in the `XML Requests` with values at runtime, dynamically.

Comment: I do have same business rule. The only difference is: I am writting the Token value in the cookie using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("SignInKey", SessionCollection.AppUser.SignInKey)); Anyway to add an Extraction Rule that can read from Cookie instead?